# Disable taglibs in web.xml on Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, jsp-tags, web.xml

My app is scanning for tld paths during the bootup and i realize that it is taking more than 15 secs.

How do i disable it completely? I am using appengine.

Thanks.